# IBM LSF handling of stdout for bsub jobs entering SSUSP state

Tags: cluster-computing, lsf

For those familiar with IBM LSF - I am wondering if someone knows how to configure a job, via the job itself or a global config file, to handle stdout when a job enters SSUSP states. As far as I understand my issue, a job will restart from the beginning after entering SSUSP but the stdout is appended and not overwritten. Below is an example of a submission. This happens for a variety of functions regardless of output type (compressed or plain text file)

```
bsub -R 'span[hosts=1]' -N -o stdout.file myFunction ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution depending on the specific use case is to pass `-oo` instead of `-o` as this will overwrite instead of append the output, but I haven't been able to address the original issue...

https://scicomp.ethz.ch/wiki/LSF_mini_reference